# add different background color between odd and even when creating tr in each

Tags: jquery

```
 var rowCount = 0;
 var trCount;

  // Set start each at second tr
  $('#list tr').each(function(index, tr) {
    // Count
    rowCount++;

    // Create tr
    trCount = $('<tr/>');

    // Create row number 1,2,3
    trCount.append("<td>" + rowCount + "</td>");

    // Append tr to display table
    tableContent.append(trCount);
  });
```

i am using the to create tr to my table , but my intention here is there will be different background-color between odd and even tr number , so how do i do this ?

something like this

```
$("tr:odd").css("background-color", "#E5E5E5");
$("tr:even:gt(0)").css("background-color", "#c7d4e5");
```

how do i append different back ground color when creating `<tr>`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in pure CSS and it will apply no matter how much javascript you throw at it.

```
tr:nth-of-type(even) {
    background-color:#E5E5E5;
}
tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background-color:#c7d4e5;
}
```

Comment: @PatrickMoore, You probably won't agree with this, but w3s says otherwise: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp

Comment: A better reference would perhaps be http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3

Comment: Thanks @MikeMcCaughan, I tried looking at caniuse first, but I couldn't find the objects I was looking for.

Comment: @Andreas No problem :)